# Why wouldn't the table show in the local host (jsp file)?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, javabeans

I wrote a jsp file for the web.And I use tomcat 8.5.
 However, the table didn't come out as I want it to be. 
 the  part came out right but the  part is totally empty even no frames.

Here is the code below.

```
  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"
pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*,enrollBean.*, Attendance.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html><head><title> </title></head>
<body>
    <%@ include file="top_project.jsp"%>
    <% if (session_id == null)  response.sendRedirect("login.jsp"); %>
    String c_id= request.getParameter("c_id");
    <table width="75%" align="center" border>   <br>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>4</th>
            <th>5</th>
            <th>6</th>
            <th>7</th>
            <th>8</th>
        </tr>
    <br>
    <jsp:useBean id="att" class="AttendanceBean.AttendanceBean"/>
    <jsp:useBean id="enrollMgr" class="enrollBean.EnrollMgr" />
    <%     
        Vector vlist = enrollMgr.getEnrollList(session_id);
        int counter = vlist.size();
        Vector vlist2 = att.getAttendanceList(session_id,<%=en.getCId()%>);
        int counter = vlist2.size();


    %>

    <tr>
        <td align="center"><%=en.getCId()%></td>
        <td align="center"><%=en.getCIdNo()%></td>
        <td align="center"><%=en.getCName()%></td>
        <td align="center"><%=en.getCUnit()%></td>
        <td align="center"><%=en.getCId()%></td>
        <td align="center"><%=en.getCIdNo()%></td>
        <td align="center"><%=en.getCName()%></td>
        <td align="center"><%=en.getCUnit()%></td>
    </tr>   



    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me with fixing this error.

Answer (score 0):

At least you have the following errors in JSP / HTML source:

- `String c_id= request.getParameter("c_id");` should be enclosed with `<% ... %>`.
- `<br>` is not allowed between `<table>` and `<tr>`.
- `<br>` is not allowed between `</tr>` and `<tr>`.

Is the variable `en` introduced in `top_project.jsp`?